# Print syntax for export to csv

Tags: php, csv, export-to-excel

I want to print to excel as csv. This is where I am so far working from the answers.

```
<?php

$dbh = dbh_get();

header('Content-type: application/csv');
header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=file.csv");
readfile('file.csv');

$sql = 'select t.*
          from old t
         where t.entered >= ? and t.entered < ?
           and t.status <> \'cancel\'
           and t.ccy = \'USD\'
         order by id desc';
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);

$v = array();
$v[] = $date->format(DateTime::ISO8601);
$v[] = $dateEnd->format(DateTime::ISO8601);


$numRows = 0;
$stmt->execute($v);
while (true) {
    $r = $stmt->fetch();
    if (is_bool($r)) break;
    $numRows++;

    $bop = $r['comments'];
    $bop1 = strtok($bop, " "); //remove all but first word
    $bop2 = substr(strstr($bop," "), 1); //remove first word and space

$headers = ['PLACE','YEAR','MONTH','COY','NT','TOPS','BOP','COUNTRY','REC','SENT','DESC'];
$fields = ["Old",2015,$textDate,$r['cols'],$r['nt'],$bop1,"NTR",$r['name'],$r['first_name'],$r['last_name'],$bop2];

$fp = fopen('file.csv', 'w');
fputcsv($fp, $headers);
fputcsv($fp, $fields);
fclose($fp);
}

dbh_free($dbh);
```

Still not working with this I get one line of code printed to screen, no download. What I need is to download the csv file so I can open it with excel.

Comment: how can I undo all the edits and go back to the original question, I went down the wrong track

Answer (score 1):

Don't punish yourself by manually building a CSV. Use [PHP's built in functionality](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) instead.

```
<?php

$bop1 = 'bop1';
$bop2 = 'bop2';
$textDate = '2017-04-13';
$r = [
    'ccy' => 'ccy',
    'amount' => 'amount',
    'name' => 'name',
    'first_name' => 'first_name',
    'last_name' => 'last_name',
];

$headers = ['column1','column2','column3','column4','column5','column6','column7','column8','column9','column10','column11'];
$fields = ["Old","2015",$textDate,$r['ccy'],$r['amount'],$bop1,"NTR",$r['name'],$r['first_name'],$r['last_name'],$bop2];

$fp = fopen('file.csv', 'w');
fputcsv($fp, $headers);
fputcsv($fp, $fields);
fclose($fp);

header('Content-type: application/csv');
header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=file.csv");
readfile('file.csv');
```

Here's an updated example using your updated code:

```
<?php

$dbh = dbh_get();

$sql = 'select t.*
          from old t
         where t.entered >= ? and t.entered < ?
           and t.status <> \'cancel\'
           and t.ccy = \'USD\'
         order by id desc';
$stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);

$v = array();
$v[] = $date->format(DateTime::ISO8601);
$v[] = $dateEnd->format(DateTime::ISO8601);
$stmt->execute($v);

$fp = fopen('file.csv', 'w');
$headers = ['PLACE','YEAR','MONTH','COY','NT','TOPS','BOP','COUNTRY','REC','SENT','DESC'];
fputcsv($fp, $headers);

while ($r = $stmt->fetch()) {
    $bop = $r['comments'];
    $bop1 = strtok($bop, " "); //remove all but first word
    $bop2 = substr(strstr($bop," "), 1); //remove first word and space

    $fields = ["Old",2015,$textDate,$r['cols'],$r['nt'],$bop1,"NTR",$r['name'],$r['first_name'],$r['last_name'],$bop2];
    fputcsv($fp, $fields);
}

fclose($fp);
dbh_free($dbh);

header('Content-type: application/csv');
header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=file.csv");
readfile('file.csv');
```

Comment: Trying to work this out, if I used this how would I put header in? Also some data comes from SQL statement and would be thousands of rows

Comment: You can use a loop to add each line to the file. The headers would just be another call to fputcsv(). I'll update the answer to show that.

Comment: I can't get that to work, it doesn't download anything.

Comment: Are you trying to output the file through your browser? If so, that's additional functionality you would need to add.

Comment: No, I'm trying to make a download csv button, what I have right now works, just haven't worked out the syntax for the data. Because now I'm mixing text with variables, when it was all variables I had it working.

Comment: On another report I have it like this with all variables and it works fine print $r['id'] . ',' .
          '"' . $r['first_name'] . ' ' . $r['last_name'] . '",' .
          '"' . $r['name'] . '",' .
          '"' . $r['status'] . '",' .
          '"' . $r['text'] . '",' .
          $r['am'] . ',' .
          $r['pm'] . "\n";

Comment: Nope, but possibly I'm putting it in the wrong place? It's not triggering a download at all unsure if it's doing anything else.

Comment: This code won't trigger a download but I can show you how to do that.

Comment: Is it more complicated than just fixing the syntax on what I have already? PHP isn't my thing.

Comment: Doesn't trigger a download for me, prints everything on one line in browser. Where about do I put this code, before the sql or after? If after nothing happens, if before I just get one line

Comment: Make sure you don't have any other output before this code. And it goes after your SQL.

Comment: Ok, now it prints just one line and one row, so getting closer to working, still not a download though. I'll put up the full code instead of the one in question. Please show me what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Cool, now it seems to work, but still not triggering a download, it prints to screen

Comment: Something is outputting content before the csv file. I can't diagnose it remotely. But it does download on my system so it ultimately it should work.

Comment: Make sure there is no whitespace before the php tag, etc

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
    $data = ['Old', '2015', $textDate];
    file_put_contents('pathTofile.csv', implode(';', $data) . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
```

Update:

Now is some code more here, compared to the posted one liner. Just change the Content-Disposition header to this:

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename('file.csv').'"');
```

it forces a download. See [Content-Disposition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition) and [Read File](http://php.net/manual/de/function.readfile.php)

Comment: Why do that when you can use PHP's built in support for building CSV files?

Comment: You have one problem with the w flag, it will always clear up the file before writing something into it. With this approach you can chose You're separator. MS Excel expects ; as separator

Comment: 1. The opening of the file would not be in the loop as that would be slow and unnecessary. 2. CSV  files *by definition* have fields separated by a comma which Excel can handle perfectly fine.

Comment: 1. The PHP Manual for the 'w' says _Open for writing only; place the file pointer at the beginning of the file and truncate the file to zero length. If the file does not exist, attempt to create it._
2. Just saying because of the semicolon. Had recently some trouble with Excel and .csv files

Comment: That's only an issue if fopen() was inside the loop generating the file. It obviously won't be.

Comment: @JohnConde I think we misunderstood each other. I thought that he has an file and needs to add some content to the end. It was just one line of code there.